# TypeError: (0 , _taggedTemplateLiteralLoose2.default) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, styled-components

What is this error? so unhelpful

[image]

this is the error im seeing in the simulator

it's nothing to do with that styled component because 1) it was working for ages beforehand 2) it just randomly stopped working 3) if I comment it out or replace it, it points to somewhere else

in the console this is the error stack

[image]

as it's completely random I've tried all the usual stuff. restarting the app, resetting the cache, deleting node modules. nothing has worked. cant even google this error and find any results

this is a complete blocker for me. any ideas?

Comment: just curious about it being randomly occurring. did you use `yarn` or `npm` to install `styled-components`? and what was the version used?